# creating tables with columns yields TypeError: string operation on non-string array

Tags: python, arrays, datatable, jupyter-notebook, typeerror

I'm working on a jupyter notebook where the program runs a book and than create a table that graphs out a common list of words I've picked from the book and displays them accordingly. I definitely feel like I messed up somewhere with the table as it just isn't printing out and giving me this error provided below. I also provided the code that proceeds the table I've written out. I'm a novice programmer so I apologize for any formatting issues, thank you.

**The initialization and code that reads the book**

```
from datascience.tables import Table
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plots
plots.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action="ignore", category=FutureWarning)
from urllib.request import urlopen 
import re

def read_url(url): 
    return re.sub('\\s+', ' ', urlopen(url).read().decode())

def read_file(name):
    return re.sub('\\s+', ' ', open(name, "r").read())
```

```
book = read_url("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/8438/8438-0.txt")
chapters = book.split('CHAPTER ')[1:]
```

**The code for the table that returns the TypeError**

```
table = Table().with_columns([
    "Aristotle",   np.char.count(chapters, "Aristotle"),
    "mathematics",  np.char.count(chapters, "mathematics"),
    "science",  np.char.count(chapters, "science"),
    "morals",  np.char.count(chapters, "morals"),
    "virtues", np.char.count(chapters, "virtues"),
    "ethics", np.char.count(chapters, "ethics")
])
table
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_3412\3432057997.py in <module>
      1 table = Table().with_columns([
----> 2     "Aristotle",   np.char.count(chapters, "Aristotle"),
      3     "mathematics",  np.char.count(chapters, "mathematics"),
      4     "science",  np.char.count(chapters, "science"),
      5     "morals",  np.char.count(chapters, "morals"),

<__array_function__ internals> in count(*args, **kwargs)

B:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\defchararray.py in count(a, sub, start, end)
    505 
    506     """
--> 507     return _vec_string(a, int_, 'count', [sub, start] + _clean_args(end))
    508 
    509 

TypeError: string operation on non-string array
```

[An image of the same code working on an entirely different book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipLIU.png)

I tried essentially mirroring this format and it ended up returning me a TypeError. I double checked that all my packages in python where installed correctly and expected my code to run as well however it got this error that I can't seem to get past.

Answer (score 0):

The `count` method expects a string array as its first argument, but `chapters` is a string. To count the occurrences of each word in the list of words for each chapter, you could try using a list comprehension. Here's an example:

```
counts = []
for chapter in chapters:
    count = [np.char.count(chapter, word) for word in ["Aristotle", "mathematics", "science", "morals", "virtues", "ethics"]]
    counts.append(count)

table = Table().with_columns([
    "Aristotle", [count[0] for count in counts],
    "mathematics", [count[1] for count in counts],
    "science", [count[2] for count in counts],
    "morals", [count[3] for count in counts],
    "virtues", [count[4] for count in counts],
    "ethics", [count[5] for count in counts]
])
table
```

**UPDATE**

In order to parse this specific book, you could autogenerate in a for loop the following pattern:

```
pattern = """




BOOK I

Chapter I.


"""
```

Just replace the roman numbers and apply split method to the whole book's content loaded to memory if the code performance doesn't matter to you. Beware that this approach is **extremely unoptimised** and you only should use it for a code that you need to run once or twice. For example:

```
chapters = [book.split(pattern)[0] for pattern in patterns]
```

where patterns is a list of strings like one above

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response I really appreciate it. When I ran this instead it cleared me of all errors which was good however the table itself is only printing out the names at the top of the table with no columns showing the quantity at all. I was just confused as to what might be causing it.

Comment: Ah I see, `counts` contains an empty list. You are iteration over just a few chapter names. You need to find a common pattern that separates chapters in the book's text and apply it in your code. For example I've noticed that chapters are separated by a bunch of newlines and their names. 


The easiest thing to do is just load all the books content into a variable and do `book.split(separator)[0]`. It won't be suitable for an application that supposed to run on a server due to high memory usage of this approach, but for a code that needs to be run just once I think it's okay